# C win32 applications

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I have started C++ (I already know java) but now I'm ready for windowed applications. I'm guessing win32 is what I what to start with, but my problem is, where to start learning this or is win32 not what I want to use.

Comment: Personally, I stumbled upon [this](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) when starting and it worked well for me. I'd recommend something higher level than raw win32 if you want any productivity, though.

Comment: C or C++? They're very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do windowing, QT is your best choice in C++. win32 is just too low level these days.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great framework will try.

Answer (score 3):

There are many GUI libraries for C++ which supports windows:

- [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/) (Gtk+ bindings for C++)
- [SmartWin++](http://smartwin.sourceforge.net/)
- [V C++ GUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vgui/)
- [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)
- [QT](http://qt-project.org/)

These are the ones taken from [stroustrup faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#gui) (Why doesn't C++ have a GUI?) and there is also [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). just pick the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft actually wants everyone to write touchscreen Windows 8/WinRT apps using the latest tools.

Check out the code gallery at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/

Comment: Which would be fine if you could write properly backward compatible apps using the new API ...